# google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 RecognitionAudio not set

Tags: python, chatbot, speech-to-text, google-cloud-speech

I am having a problem with the Google Cloud Speech API, every time I run the script the error

```
six.raise_from (exceptions.from_grpc_error (exc), exc) occurs
 File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
 google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 RecognitionAudio not set.
```

he doesn't seem to recognize RecognitionAudio for some reason, I already checked the API documentation but I couldn't solve the problem
I am not understanding the reason for the error, I will leave my code here in case anyone knows and can help me, thanks

```
import telebot
import requests
from pydub import AudioSegment

import os
import io

from google.cloud import speech
from google.cloud.speech import enums
from google.cloud.speech import types

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "./chatbot.json"

token = "1233361335"
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)
downloadAudio = "https://api.telegram.org/file/bot{token}/".format(token = token)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "welcome")

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['voice'])
def handlerAudio(message):

    #get audio from telegram 
    messageVoice = message.voice

    #get download link 
    audioPath = bot.get_file(messageVoice.file_id).file_path
    audioLink = downloadAudio+audioPath

    #download file
    audioFile = requests.get(audioLink)
    audioName = "audio.ogg"

    #save locally
    open(audioName, 'wb').write(audioFile.content)

    #convert format to .WAV
    AudioSegment.from_file(audioName).export("audio.wav", format="wav")
    sound = AudioSegment.from_wav("audio.wav")
    sound = sound.set_channels(1) #convert mono
    sound.export("audio.wav", format="wav")

client = speech.SpeechClient()

with io.open("audio.wav", 'rb') as audio_file:
       content = audio_file.read()

audio = types.RecognitionAudio(content=content)
config = types.RecognitionConfig(
    encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
    sample_rate_hertz=48000,
    language_code='pt-BR')

response = client.recognize(config, audio)

for result in response.results:
  print(u'Transcript: {}'.format(result.alternatives[0].transcript))
  #bot.reply_to(message, result.alternatives[0].transcript)

bot.polling()
```